# Clearing the old activities so they don't show up on new activity click

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, notifications

So what I have is a notification in my status bar which when clicked by the user brings up an activity with no title, to replicate a dialog. But I have a problem. If I open up the app, then just click the home button, and then click the notification in my status bar. It brings up apps main activity with the notificatoins activity stacked on the top. What I want to do is make it so when I click the notification it clears all the bottom activities so that never happens. Here's the code I use to start the notification activity

```
// Send Notification
Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, Dialog.class);
intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent1, 0);
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_quick_tweet_icon)
.setContentTitle("Dialog")
.setContentText("Touch for more options")
.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
.setContentIntent(pIntent)
.setAutoCancel(false).setOngoing(true);
NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification notif = builder.getNotification();
nm.notify(1, notif);
```

Comment: You can uses `finish()` an activity when you leave it, it would be easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't going to work. You've written:

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, Dialog.class);
intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

What this says is "if activity `Dialog` already exists in the task stack, clear (finish) all activities that are on top of that in the stack before starting the `Dialog` activity. Otherwise (if there is no instance of `Dialog` already in the stack) just start the `Dialog` activity". So what you are seeing is that your `Dialog` activity is put on top of the other activities that are already in the task stack.

If you want this notification to remove all activities from the task stack and then start your `Dialog` activity, I suggest you do the following:

Create the notification like this:

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, MyRootActivity.class);
intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent1.putExtra("startDialog", true);
```

in this case, `MyRootActivity` must be the root activity of the task (ie: the one that has ACTION=MAIN and CATEGORY=LAUNCHER in the manifest).

In `onCreate()` of `MyRootActivity` do this:

```
super.onCreate(...);
if (getIntent().hasExtra("startDialog")) {
    // User has selected the notification, so we show the Dialog activity
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Dialog.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish(); // finish this activity
    return; // Return here so we don't execute the rest of onCreate()
}
... here is the rest of your onCreate() method...
```

Hopefully this is clear.

Comment: Thank you so much for that. And for explaining why it wasn't working for me.

Comment: Just one more question, how would I make this work as a service. Because in my service class it doesn't recognize the method finish(); or getIntent();  @David Wasser

Comment: Sorry, don't really understand that question. You can't show dialogs in a service. What are you trying to do?

Comment: It's not an actual dialog it's an activity called dialog, because it replicates one. Since it has no title bar, and it's just like a fourth of an activity. The code worked on a normal activity but not on a service one.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand. If you can post more code from your service and explain what isn't working I'll be glad to help